# No viewdata item of type IEnumerable on web server and not in dev

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

In my html I have this code

```
 <div>
    <label for="ddlBranch">Branch:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("Branches", "select branch");       
 </div>
```

In my controller Index ActionResult I have this

```
var getBranches = _edmDataService.RetrieveAllBranches();
ViewBag.Branches = new SelectList(getBranches, "Id", "BranchName");
```

This runs locally on my dev box without a problem. By the time I deploy my code to the 
webserver, I got this error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Branches'.

Here is my post method

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Select(bool isChecked, string id)
{
    var selectList = (List<string>)HttpContext.Session["SelectList"] ?? new List<string>();
    if (isChecked && !selectList.Contains(id))
    {
        selectList.Add(id);
    }
    else if (!isChecked && selectList.Contains(id))
    {
        selectList.RemoveAll(s => s == id);
    }
    HttpContext.Session["SelectList"] = selectList;
    return Content("OK");
}
```

Comment: The error means that `ViewBag.Branches` is `null`

Comment: This runs locally for me meaning that it is not null. It only fails when I deploy to the webserver

Comment: Which suggests your `var getBranches = _edmDataService.RetrieveAllBranches();` code is returning `null` when you deploy!

Comment: Alternatively, this is happening when you submit the form (and have not reassigned the `ViewBag` property if you return the view)

Comment: So what do i do to fix this? Can it be that after deploying, I don't have access to the database again?

Comment: Its more likely the second issue. Show your POST method

Comment: I added my post method.

Comment: You don't return the view in the POST method so that is not the issue. Which means that in the GET method, `ViewBag.Branches` is null when you return the view. Suggest you temporarily hard code a `new List<SelectListItem>` with a few values just for testing that there is not anything else that could be causing the value of `ViewBag.Branches` to be reset to `null`

Comment: Having said that, its unclear what your dropdownlist is doing - The POST method does not have a parameter for `Branches` so what is the point of the control if your not posting its value.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try all what you suggested.